# Convert REST API to websocket client

Tags: c#, api, websocket

I have existing C# web api, I want to convert it into websocket base API.

Where user can subscribe to the end point and then I can post data to user from some other service.

How can I implement this? Any guidlines will be great help.

I have tried doing it with websocket handler but it just send data by making call inside the controller method. I want to be able to push data from other service once the user subscribed to the websocket API end point.

Comment: I used [fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) to host websocket server but I hope someone can tell me how to use websocket in ASP.NET Core. I tried [this](https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2019/01/20/how-to-use-websockets-with-asp-net-core-with-an-example/) solution but it didn't work. Both server and client threw an exception.

Comment: Use signalr, it's really simple to implement. Give it a try.

Comment: Have you checked the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-2.2+) ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I created websoket hub and then added authorization on it where needed. Works fine as per what I wanted.

still if anyone has better solution, please suggest.